# Bioconductor package development S3 vs S4

Tags: r, package, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I'm working with a lab developing a package for consideration submission to Bioconductor.

Currently, it uses S3 class objects. Everything that I've seen so far in bioncoductor uses S4. Before we attempt to submit, we are wondering if the S3 would disqualify the package. Looking for advice.

Comment: You can read the package submission guidelines: https://www.bioconductor.org/developers/package-submission/. Are you interfacing with any existing bioconductor classes? The expectation seems to be that you reused core functionality from other packages when available. But if you are doing something compeltely different, that might not matter (but if it's disconnected why try for bioconductor rather than CRAN). This questions is a bit too abstract to really be answerable.